Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-jammy.list (Component)
Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-jammy.list (Component)
I'm running Lubuntu Jammy and get the above error. I'm not good at troubleshooting and have been stumbling through stuff trying to interpret my fix from other versions of ubuntu. i tried to install multiple software at once and something messed up. before or after i tried to add a software source in the other tab on software sources. This is a paste of what it is saying:
edwin@thor-server:~$ sudo autoremove
[sudo] password for edwin: 
sudo: autoremove: command not found
edwin@thor-server:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 133, in <module>
    m = MetaReleaseCore(useDevelopmentRelease=options.devel_release,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 103, in __init__
    cache = apt.Cache()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 214, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
apt_pkg.Error: E:Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-jammy.list (Component), E:The list of sources could not be read.
edwin@thor-server:~$ sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
E: Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-jammy.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.


Good job getting a paste of the error!

E:Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-jammy.list Review that file, see if you can find the malformed entry. If you cannot locate it, then paste the contents of the file into your question above.


user535733 I'm new to the whole process and can you tell me how to review that file please?


Edit Sources, best to have backup
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup &
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

thank you. i will try it in the morning.

This question is similar to: E: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

i tried and got this now:  pk-client-error-quark: E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_canoical_com_-jammy.list (Component)
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-jammy-jammy.list (Component)
E: Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-jammy.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
(281)

I think you are right and the answer is in that link so im going to reformat

I got lost trying but it is due to lack of knowledge to do the needed instructions. I linked the closest answer and am reformatting with kubuntu.
